# sql server syntax error near where in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to get the last status a customer had. By browsing examples, I have put together this query, which works:

```
SELECT table.Card, 
    table.Type, 
    table.Date, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER   
        (PARTITION by table.CARD ORDER BY table.date DESC, table.TYPE, table.DATE) rn 
 FROM table 
 WHERE table.Type = 'active' or table.Type = 'erased'
```

From there, I just need those records where rn=1, but as soon as I try to use itas a subquery as shown below, I get a syntaxis error:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT table.Card, 
        table.Type, 
        table.Date, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER   
            (PARTITION by table.CARD ORDER BY table.date DESC, table.TYPE, table.DATE) rn 
     FROM table 
     WHERE table.Type = 'active' or table.Type = 'erased'
) WHERE rn=1
```

It must something simple I am just missing, but I am totally confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your subquery needs an alias. `) AS x WHERE rn = 1;`

Answer (score 2):

You should assign an alias to the INNER select. Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT table.Card, 
        table.Type, 
        table.Date, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER   
            (PARTITION by table.CARD ORDER BY table.date DESC, table.TYPE, table.DATE) rn 
     FROM table 
     WHERE table.Type = 'active' or table.Type = 'erased'
) foo WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: I'm glad. Please accept the answer if it works for you. Remember, if you use alias on your sub-query then you can JOIN it with some other tables using that alias :)